# Show different elements of a store in different grids

Tags: extjs

All data is in one store:

```
{'Alice','Apple',5,$.25,'fruit'}
{'Bob','Yogurt',2,$.35,'dairy'}
{'Bob','Banana',5,$.25,'fruit'}
{'Bob','Brokkoli',4,$.35,'vegetable'}
{'Eve','Grapefruit',2,$.40,'fruit'}
{'Eve','Goat cheese',2,$2.40,'dairy'}
```

I have multiple grids, one for every product group; which are called exactly like the product group they represent: "vegetable", "fruit", "dairy" etc.

Is there any possibility to tell the store's filter that it has to filter differently, depending on which grid is accessing the data for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the filters are set on the store, and not the grid, you will need to create a separate store for each grid.

You could get the data from the server, and then load it into a different store for each grid, with appropriate filters set on each store. This way, you can display different data in each grid, but you only have to make one call to the server. (If you are already using a local store, then you already have the data in one place, so just load that into the different stores)

Comment: For future readers, I'd like to point out that ExtJS 6 has a ChainedStore for exactly that purpose. Prior versions did not have something similar.